# CakePHP saveAll() function for saving multiple models data at one call

Tags: database, model, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.1 and I wanna save multiple models data at one call using saveAll() function.. The attributes for each model as follows.

```
Company(id, name);
User(id, name, company_id);
Oauth(id, details, user_id);
GoogleAnalytic(id, name, company_id);
Setting(id, user_id, google_analytic_id);
```

While user is signing into an application, I wanna save these at one call.

The model structure is as follows.

```
Company(hasOne => GoogleAnalytic, hasMany => User);
User(belongsTo => Company, hasOne => Setting, hasMany => Oauth);
GoogleAnalytic(belongsTo => Company, hasMany => Setting);
Setting(belongsTo => GoogleAnalytic, User);
```

I tried a lot but didn't save those at one call. How to save these all at one call?
The work will be appreciated..